# An error occurred due comparing two variables

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11

Here is my code for login. As you can see, I have my username and password pre defined.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var _username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var _password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var _login_button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    let username = "Kiarash"
    let password = "Test"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: Any) {

         if(_username.text == username && _password.text == password)
        {
           label.text = "You are Logged in!"

    }
    }
}
```

But when I enter the correct username and password, it throw below error.

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8b9450ac60
2020-05-03 19:44:02.481826-0700 KCMLogin[9156:552975] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8b9450ac60'
```

I am not sure why this happen, Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: The implication is that the `label` outlet has gotten messed up.

Comment: @matt How can i fix it?

Comment: If the value is of type UITextField!, it gets very tricky when it's **nil**.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the current `Referencing Outlets` from `label` and reconnect `label` to `view controller`.